# Azure Diagnostic Configuration from Separate Assembly

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

We are developing several Azure-based applications in C# and are attempting to centralize some common code in a utility library. One of the common functions is Diagnostic monitoring setup.

We created a class that simplifies the configuration of diag collection, log transfer, etc.

The main issue we are facing is that when we run our code while the class lives in a different assembly from the WebRole or WorkerRole, the diagnostic information is never collected and transferred to azure table storage. If we move the class to the same project as the Web/Worker role, then everything works as expected.

Is there something that either the DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration(); or the DiagnosticMonitor.Start(StorageConnectionStringKey, _diagConfig); doesn't like about being in another assembly? I'm stumped!

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Which part is not working here?  Trace Logs not getting transferred?  That seems to be the one that most people have issues with.

We do something similar and have no issues.  Typically when you don't see stuff getting transferred it's because the current process where the listener is getting configured is not always the same one where tracing occurs (especially when dynamically adding to trace listener collection).  Notably, a lot of users find this issue with web apps in Windows Azure.

What are you expecting to see transferred?  Perf counters?  Traces?  Event Logs? etc.

Comment: We are actually setting up Trace, Perf Counters and Event Logs. None of them seem to work. Essentially, we refactored the code to take the "DefaultInitialConfiguration" as a dependency to the constructor and made the DiagnosticMonitor.Start call from the OnStart (instead of the library) and everything else started working.